# Label axis with derivative in R

Tags: r, math, plot, graph, axis-labels

What is the incatation to create math notation for an axis label of a derivative in R?

Desired output for axis label is:

[image]

Tried so far:

```
plot(0,xlab=expression(delta~y~'/'~delta~x),ylab=expression(dy/dx))
```

[image]

Documentation reviewed:

- http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/mathematical-annotation-in-r/
- http://www.astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/grDevices/html/plotmath.html
- [There's seriously no reason why LaTeX markup via MathJax shouldn't be enabled on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plot(0, xlab=expression(frac(italic(dy), italic(dx))), ylab=expression(dy/dx))
```

You might also need to adjust positioning to get it to fit correctly. Compare:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(0, xlab=expression(frac(italic(dy), italic(dx))), ylab=expression(dy/dx))

plot(0, xlab="", ylab=expression(dy/dx))
mtext(side=1, text=expression(frac(italic(dy), italic(dx))), line=4)
```

[image]

To plot the y-label rotated, it looks like `mtext` doesn't support the `srt` (string rotation) parameter, so I guess you have to do it with `text`. I've placed the label manually, but you could probably do it programmatically by querying the various plot coordinate values.

```
plot(0, xlab="", ylab="")
mtext(side=1, text=expression(frac(italic(dy), italic(dx))), line=4)
text(0.45,0, labels=expression(frac(italic(dy), italic(dx))), srt=0, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]